# Adding an object to a list in a different thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, synchronization, thread-safety

I am writing an application where i have 2 threads. One for GUI and one for computation stuff. They look something like this:

First Thread:

```
while True:
    for task in tasks:
        task.update()
```

And meanwhile there is running a second thread(GUI) where User pushes a button and a new task is added to tasks:

```
def addTask(self,new_task):
    tasks.append(new_task)
```

My questions are: Do I have 100% sure that it will come up in the last iteration of the loop? Is there a better way to do this? I mean, I cannot afford losing such task in my project.
And the most important thing is that i CANT resume work in First Thread, it has to work all the time, because it is connected to an API with request-per-second limitation.